# Area enclosed between the curves

Tags: definite-integrals

Find the area enclosed between $y=1/2$ and $ y= \cos x $ for $x =[0,2π]$ 
I am a bit confused with this question because there is no area bound between these graphs and a book suggests to enclose areas using $Y$ axis which I find is a bit incorrect 
If I am wrong please let me know

Comment: What makes you say there is no area bound between the graphs? Can we see your plot?

Comment: What do you mean to enclose areas using the $y$-axis? There is clearly a certain amount of area bounded by those two curves. Just plot them in an online graphing calculator and you will see.

Comment: Ok Thanks I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check this plot(courtesy Wolfram Alpha).
[image]

The area may be calculated by evaluating definite integrals between intervals,whose boundaries are on the solution of cos x = 1/2.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
Solve the equation $$\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$ for $$0\le x\le 2\pi$$

Comment: Sir I solved it the same way but aren't we using the Y axis to enclose the area which isn't correct .

Comment: It is the area between $y=\frac{1}{2},y=\cos(x)$?

Comment: If so then $$A_1=\int_{0}^{\pi/3}\cos(x)-\frac{1}{2}dx$$

Comment: And $$A_2=\int_{\frac{5}{3}\pi}^{2\pi}\cos(x)-\frac{1}{2}dx$$

Comment: But the area from π/3 and 5π/3 is also enclosed

Comment: Yes, this is true: $$A_3=\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{5\pi}{3}}\frac{1}{2}-\cos(x)dx$$